# Errors while reversing a String(Sentence ) in C with for loop (assigning it to another string.)

Tags: c, string, data-structures

https://github.com/ashwinidotx/Daily-Coding-Problmes/blob/master/Operations%20with%20names.c

Check out my code, I am able to Print a sentence but the Compiler is not executing the Reverse loop;
Here's the code snippet I am using to reverse the string.

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    reverse[i]=name[size-i-1];

printf("\nReverse: ");
for(i=0;i!='\0';i++)
    printf("%c",reverse[i]);
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't execute anything, it just _compiles_ your program. BTW please read this: [ask]  and this: [mcve]

Comment: You are suposed to produce a [mcve] and post it, not link to external code. "but the Compiler is not executing" no that's not what happens here. Use your debugger to trace your program execution line by line. Observe how variables change during execution. Also get a C book and work through exercises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to terminate the `char` array `reverse` with null terminator after the first `for` loop. So add the following **after the first `for` loop**. Otherwise, you will end up printing junk characters to your output as you will read beyond what is allowed.

```
reverse[i] = '\0';
```

You should compare the character in the array `reverse` to the null terminator. Instead you are comparing `i` with it. So change the second for loop like this:

```
for(i=0; reverse[i]!='\0'; i++)
    printf("%c",reverse[i]);
```

Comment: ok so I changed my code to this and it's printing garbage value now

for (i=0;i<size;i++)
  reverse[i]=name[size-i-1];
 
 printf("\nReverse: ");
 for(i=0;i<size;i++){printf("%c",reverse[i]);}

Comment: I tested this on my PC. It works fine. Have you done both the things I suggested?

Comment: The code you pasted in the comment does not include the changes I suggested.

Comment: yeah, I copied the wrong code.
I edited it afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `i!='\0'`, it should be `reverse[i]!='\0'`

```
printf("\nReverse: ");
for(i=0;reverse[i]!='\0';i++)
    printf("%c",reverse[i]);
```